# Removing multiple space using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a sentence :

```
171211 22043707      21641 xxxx     xxxxxxx  From (,,xxxx,xxxx) Vxxxx1:  xxxxxx
171212 13441585        417 xxxx     xxxxxxxx Server manager informed of process termination, pinfo =  x,0000032585 13:44:15
```

Issue is the space between `171211 22043707` and `21641` varies. I want to replace it with one space. 
How do I do this? Which `sed` command can match for one or more spaces?

Comment: What exactly is your result?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19014/how-to-strip-multiple-spaces-to-one-using-sed, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092360/how-to-remove-extra-spaces-in-bash

Comment: 171211 22043707"      "xxxx xxxxxxx"     "xxxx xxxxxxx  From (,,CWXN,CWBA) VROHS01:  ARXIDFS.ATOM .please see the gap which i have given in quotes..

Comment: Add this to your question and prefix it with four spaces.

Answer (score 5):

With `tr` you can do that much easier:

```
tr -s ' '
```

from `tr` man:

```
 -s, --squeeze-repeats
          replace each input sequence of a repeated character that is
          listed in SET1 with a single occurrence of that character
```

Comment: While that's a solution to the problem it's not an answer to the question as OP asks explicitly for `sed`.

Comment: True. But it seems to me that OP just wants to solve the problem and is not aware of other tools.

Answer (score 3):

```bsh
sed 's/ \{2,\}/ /' # or
sed -E 's/ {2,}/ /'
```

This command replaces the first occurence of two or more (`{2,}`) spaces with a single space, this matches the first big gap in your example. If you want to replace *every* occurence of two or more spaces, add a `g` to the end of the command:

```bsh
sed 's/ \{2,\}/ /g' # or
sed -E 's/ {2,}/ /g'
```

If you want to replace only a sequence of e.g. three or more spaces change the digit accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Read `man sed` carefully, and `man 7 regex`, and you'll understand:

```
sed -e 's/ \+/ /g'
```

will change multiple adjacent spaces to a single space on the whole line.

Comment: I suggest to remove `g`.

Comment: @Cyrus Without the `g` suffix, `sed` will collapse only the first occurrance of multiple spaces.

Comment: I have understood the question in such a way that he only wants to reduce the spaces between "171211 22043707" and "21641".

Comment: @Cyrus In a comment he mentioned to gaps he wants to eliminate.

Comment: You can omit `-e`.